# How to implement Access control for Headers in r?

Tags: r, data-mining, data-science-model

When i call service from client side then give that error.
No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. Origin ‘null’ is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I was trying to set request header-

cors <- function(res) {
res$setHeader(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin”, “*”)
plumber::forward()
}

But it’s not working

Please tell me how to set request header in plumber.

Again, I cannot install httr and curl packages, is these packages needed in this case.